# CSS - issues with div positioning and sizing on resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm an absolute beginner making my first website (link to the js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/helenestelle/3vua98ha/)).

I'm having some issues with the #about-box div:

1. When I resize the window the top edge moves down, instead of staying fixed. I've tried to use percentages instead of pixels so I'm not sure why this is happening.
2. I've used media queries to make it look ok on different resolutions, however on the `max-width 750px` the about-box div won't fill the width of the screen despite the width being set at 100%.

Like I said, I'm a beginner here so the code may be a tad messy, and it does have some notes in it. Any help would be really appreciated!

The code is below:

```css
/************************************
    NAVIGATION
************************************/
.logo {
 float: left;
 max-width: 200px
}

nav {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 10px;
 padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
}

nav a {
 padding: 15px 10px;
}

/*****************************************
    HEADER IMAGE
******************************************/
#header-image {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}

#header-image img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*****************************************
    SITE BODY
******************************************/
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}

/*selected nav link*/
nav a:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
}

/*****************************************
    IMAGE
******************************************/
.hero-image img {
 width: 75%;
 max-height: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 right: 1.5em;
 top: 30px;
 float: right;
 z-index: -1;
}

/*****************************************
    ABOUT BOX
******************************************/
#about-box {
 max-width: 50%;
 max-height: auto;
 border: none;
 background-color: #EBECE2;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: /*13em;*/ 60%;
 margin: /*300px 60px*/ 20% 5%;
}

h2 {
 max-font-size: 28px;
 font-family: helvetica, ariel;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px;
 margin-top: 1em margin-bottom:0em;
}

p {
 max-font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: georgia; ariel;
 font-style: italic;
 padding: 30px;
 margin: -3em .5em .5em 2em;
}

a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*******************************************
    CTA BUTTON
*******************************************/
button {
 margin: 0 0 50px;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 background: transparent;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 1em;
 cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

button span {
 display: block;
}

button>span {
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #979797;
 padding: 0 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-family: georgia;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
 background-color: #979797;
}

/*******************************************************
    DESTINATIONS
*******************************************************/
ul.rig {
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 0px;
 margin-left: -2.5%;
}

ul.rig li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10% 0 2.5% 2.5%;
 background: #fff;
 border: /*1px solid #ddd*/ none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-size: 1rem;
 vertical-align: top;
 box-shadow: /*0 0 5px #ddd*/ none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.rig li img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: /*0 0 10px*/ 0;
}

ul.rig li h3 {
 margin: 0 0 5px;
}

ul.rig li p {
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #999;
}

ul.rig.columns-3 li {
 width: 30.83%;
}

/*RESPONSIVE CSS*/
@media ( max-width : 750px) {
 #about-box {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: /*13em;*/ 30%;
  margin: /*300px 60px*/ 20%;
 }
 .hero-image img {
  display: none;
 }
 .rig {
  margin: 300px 0;
 }
}

@media ( max-width : 480px) {
 ul.grid-nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
 }
 ul.grid-nav li a {
  display: block;
 }
 ul.rig {
  margin /*-left*/: 350px 0;
 }
 ul.rig li {
  width: 100% !important; /* over-ride all li styles */
  margin: 0 0 20px;
 }
 #about-box {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  height: auto;
  top: /*13em;*/ 30%;
  margin: /*300px 60px*/ 20% auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/sitetitle.jpg"
   alt="and then we went" class="logo">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>

 <div id="header-image">
  <img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/homepagebanner.jpg"
   alt="and then we went" class="header">
 </div>

 <div id="about-box">
  <h2>For Explorers</h2>
  <p>&thenwewent is a collection of images, quotes and stories from
   a hand-picked selection of the world’s most exotic destinations.</p>
  <button>
   <span><span>Read More</span></span>
  </button>
 </div>

 <div class="hero-image">
  <img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/about-photo.jpg"
   alt="about this site">
 </div>

 <ul class="rig columns-3">
  <li><img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/png.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/wildwest.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://andthenwewent.space/img/amazon.jpg" /></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: where do you want #about-box stay in your page ? and when it resize should it stay fixed in the same place?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use

```
#about-box
  height: auto;
  top: 13em; 30%;
```

I just commented it and everything is working fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I was missing that :-)

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as a correct one? You'll help me build good reputation on the stack overflow :) If you have any other questions, feel free to ask!